Error creating a table when referencing a foreign key
I am creating a table and have numerous foreign keys. However, the very last foreign key in the code gives me an error code. If I remove this line the code works. Can anyone explain what is wrong?
This is the last two lines of the code:
    FOREIGN KEY (start_address_id) REFERENCES Addresses(address_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (end_address_id) REFERENCES Addresses(address_id)
    );

if I remove the Foreign key in the last line, for end_address_id, the code works. I am a total novice at MYSQL so hopefully it is a simple solution I can understand!

Provide complete CREATE TABLE for the table which you try to create, for Addresses table, and complete error message text. I predict the datatypes non-compatibility.

It would be good if you provide schema for both tables. Refering to your comment there can be a possiblity of "Mismatched Data Types" in both table column which won't allow user and throw error while creating Foreign key.

Thank you for trying to help. I have now managed to sort the issue
